# Database TypeError in ArangoDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, arangodb, foxx

Applying this tutorial without Foxx :

http://www.ashishblog.com/getting-start-with-arangodb-using-nodejs-nodejs-ejs-arangojs/

Node.js 8.11.1 (x64)

arangoDB 3.3.7-1_win64

arangojs@6.2.4

ERROR MESSAGES IN THE BROWSER

@ http://localhost:3000/users

```js
TypeError: db.database is not a function
    at Object.getAllUsers (H:\TEST\app\services\DataServices.js:6:13)
    at H:\TEST\app\routes\users.js:8:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (H:\TEST\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

Services\ DataServices.js :

```js
var Database = require('arangojs');
var db = new Database({url:'http://127.0.0.1:8529'});
module.exports = {
 getAllUsers : function()
 {
  return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
     .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.query('FOR x IN User RETURN x');})  
     .then(function (cursor) { return  cursor.all();});  
 },
 getUserByKey : function(userKey)
 {
  var bindVars = {'userKey': userKey};
  return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
     .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.query('FOR x IN User FILTER x._key == @userKey RETURN x',bindVars);})  
     .then(function (cursor) { return  cursor.all();});  
 },
 addUser : function(user)
 {
  return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
         .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.collection('User');})    
         .then(function (collection) { return collection.save(user);});
 },
 updateUser : function(user)
 {
  var bindVars = {'key': user.key, 'username': user.username,"email":user.email };
  return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
     .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.query('FOR x IN User FILTER x._key == @key UPDATE x WITH { username:@username, email:@email } IN User',bindVars );})    
          .then(function (cursor) { return cursor.all();});         
 },
 removeUser : function(userKey)
 {
  var bindVars = {'userKey': userKey};
  return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
         .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.query('FOR x IN User FILTER x._key == @userKey REMOVE x IN User LET removed = OLD RETURN removed', bindVars);})
         .then(function (cursor) {return cursor.all();});
 } 
}
```

What is wrong with this :

```js
return db.database('nodeArangoWebAppDB')
```

What would be the right coding (without Foxx) ?

What changes should be made implementing Foxx ?

---

EDIT #1 :

What is wrong with this :

```js
var db = new arangojs.Database('http://127.0.0.1:8529')
db.useDatabase("nodeArangoWebAppDB");
db.useBasicAuth("root", "root");

module.exports = {
 getAllUsers : function(){
 return db._query('FOR x IN User RETURN x')
  .then(value) => { return value.all();};
},
```

```js
H:\TEST\app>npm start

> app@0.0.0 start H:\TEST\app
> node ./bin/www

H:\TEST\app\services\DataServices.js:8
        return db._query('FOR x IN User RETURN x')
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\TEST\app\routes\users.js:3:15)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Should we use Webpack ?

Comment: All functions use the variable `db`, but isn't it `undefined` because it is not in the scope of the exported object?

Comment: So what is missing in the tutorial and where ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this. The below code seems to work

```
var arangojs = require("arangojs");
var db = new arangojs.Database('http://127.0.0.1:8529');
db.useDatabase("superrango");
db.useBasicAuth("root", "asdf");

module.exports = {
    getAllUsers : function()
    {
                 return db.query('FOR x IN Users RETURN x')
                         .then((value) => {return value.all();});

    }
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .    @ H:\TEST\app\services\DataServices.js:8
        return db.query('FOR x IN User RETURN x')

Comment: Are you using a password with an @ sign or something.

Comment: "root" as above

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple years later, but I had the exact same issue after changing to version 8 of the arangojs module in node.  Turns out, to use a different database you supply this in an object in the database constructor:

```
const db = new arangojs.Database({
  url:'http://172.25.255.4:8529',
  databaseName: 'my_database',
  auth: { username:'root', password:'my_assword'}
})
```

The tutorial I was following specified using v5 and used the 'old' methods to connect.  So with (at least v8), you supply the connection as an object.