# Arngodb, Arangojs error while retriving data

Tags: arangodb

I get this error when trying to retrieve data from arangodb.

TypeError: db.database is not a function

```
var Database = require('arangojs');
var db = new Database({url:'http://127.0.0.1:8529'});
module.exports = {
    getAllUsers : function()
    {
        return db.database('superrango')
                 .then(function (mydb) {return mydb.query('FOR x IN Users RETURN x');})
                 .then(function (cursor) { return  cursor.all();});
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280066/database-typeerror-in-arangodb-with-node-js

Comment: You have not defined the solutions there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it

```
var arangojs = require("arangojs");
var db = new arangojs.Database('http://127.0.0.1:8529');
db.useDatabase("superrango");
db.useBasicAuth("root", "asdf");

module.exports = {
    getAllUsers : function()
    {
                 return db.query('FOR x IN Users RETURN x')
                         .then((value) => {return value.all();});

    }
}
```